# How can Ifetch Users conversation list where user A has conversations with User B,C And D?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA but I'm stuck on how to create a query based on who a user has chat history with.

I have the two objects of which Message is an entity while Chat-Message is not.

You can take a look from both classes and guide me on how I can create a spring data JPA query that queries certain users conversations with other users:

```java
@Entity 
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    String message;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="fromUser",nullable=false)
    private User fromUser;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="toUser",nullable=false)
    private User toUser;

   
    public Message() { }
   
    public Message(User fromUser, User toUser, String message) {
        this.fromUser=fromUser;
        this.toUser=toUser;
        this.message=message;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    
    // getters and setters
    
}

public class ChatMessage {

    Long id;
    String message;
    String sender;
    String username;
    Long  senderId;
    

    public ChatMessage() { }
   
    // getters and setters

    public ChatMessage(Message m, Boolean isReply) {
        this.sender = m.getFromUser().getFirstname() + " " + m.getFromUser().getLastname();
        this.message = m.getMessage();
        this.senderId = m.getFromUser().getId();
        this.id = m.getId();
    }
  
}
```

My possible endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/conversations",produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Message>  myMessages(Principal principal){
     
    String thisUser=principal.getName();
    User user=userServiceImpl.findByUsername(thisUser);
   // List<Message>messages=messageServiceImpl.finddAll();
   List<Message> messages=messageServiceImpl.fetchMessages(user.getId());

    return messages;
}
```

Note that Chat-Message is just an object class for carrying WebSocket messages. My Message Repo:

```
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message,Long>{

}
```

Image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVbP3.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what exactly you need here, and what `messageServiceImpl` does, for instance. But, maybe this will be useful:

```java
public interface MessageRepository extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
    // if we get all messages your user sent or received - would it be
    // what you mean here a "conversation" ?
    List<Message> findByFromUserIdOrToUserId(Long id);


    // or you can use @Query to achieve the same
    @Query("select m from Message m where m.fromUser.id = :id or m.toUser.id = :id")
    List<User> findMessagesForUser(Long id);
}
```

You can also find more details of how to create queries using Spring Data in their [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

Comment: cheers i found the solution!!